# How to change the color of a cell based on the value of other cells in google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

I am aware of conditional formatting in google sheets, but I have a kind of specific use case.

I want the cell n in column `A` (and all the way down) to be green if **ALL** the cells in columns `N`, `O` or `P` have the word `pass` in them

But I want the cell n in column `A` to be red if **ANY** of the cells in `N`, `O` or `P` contain `fail` regardless if they also contain `pass`

Is there a way this can be done?

Comment: Do you have an example sheet you can share?

Answer (score 3):

### Explanation:

- You can use [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) to achieve your goal and in
  particular an [onEdit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) function to mimic the automatic (on edit)
  updates of the conditional formatting.
- The following script will get the values of all cells in **N**, **O**
  and **P** columns and if **all** of these values are *pass* then it
  will [set](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundcolor) the background color of column **A** to green. On the
  other hand, if at least one of them is not *pass*, it will set the
  color of column **A** to red. Feel free to change `sheet_name` to your own sheet name.

---

### Solution:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  
 const sheet_name = 'Sheet1';
 const col = e.range.getColumn();
 const as = e.source.getActiveSheet();
 
 if(as.getName() === sheet_name && col>13 && col<17){
 
   const data = as.getRange('N1:P').getValues().flat();
   const range = as.getRange('A1:A');
   const allEqual = arr => arr.every( v => v === arr[0] );
   
   if(allEqual(data)){
     range.setBackground("green");
  }
   else {
     range.setBackground("red");
  }
 }
}
```

---

### Instructions/Demonstration:

[image: demonstration]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use formulas instead of a script you can always use the following 2 rules:

**1st rule:**

> ...cell n in column `A` (and all the way down) to be green if **ALL** the cells in columns `N`, `O` or `P` have the word `pass` in them

```
=COUNTIF($B$1:$D,">""")+COUNTIF($B$1:$D,"")=COUNTIF(ArrayFormula(REGEXMATCH($B$1:$D,"\bpass\b")),true)
```

[image]

**2nd rule:**

> ...cell n in column `A` to be red if **ANY** of the cells in `N`, `O` or `P` contain `fail` regardless if they also contain `pass`

```
=COUNTIF(ArrayFormula(REGEXMATCH($B$1:$D,"\bfail\b")),true)>0
```

[image]